# signal R and windows azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, signalr

So I created a service bus queue and the client puts message in this queue and the bus listener gets it and does the work.All this is written in asp.net C#.
What i want to do is notify the client when the work is done and for this I want to use signalR. But the signalR clients are usually written in javascript. How can I do this. Use signalr and the bus service queue

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at [signalr.net](http://signalr.net/)? As it stands, your question is fairly broad - probably lots of ways to implement SignalR.

Comment: yes i did look at signalr.net
I know how to use bus service and signalR separately but I am having a tough time putting them together.
I looked at signalR scaleout with Azure bus service but that not what I want to do

Answer (score 0):

SignalR also has a .Net client , so it will fit into your asp.net technology stack
[SignalR .Net client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client), You will first need to establish connection :

```
 var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://www.contoso.com/");
 IHubProxy stockTickerHubProxy =  hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("StockTickerHub");
 stockTickerHubProxy.On<Stock>("UpdateStockPrice", stock =>
 Console.WriteLine("Stock update for {0} new price {1}", stock.Symbol,  stock.Price));
 await hubConnection.Start();
```

and create a client side function the server can use :

```
stockTickerHub.On("notify", () =>
    // Context is a reference to SynchronizationContext.Current
    Context.Post(delegate
    {
        textBox.Text += "Notified!\n";
    }, null)
);
```

and finally call the client side method from your server side :

```
public void ServerNotify()
{
    context.Clients.Others.notify(stock);
}
```